# Angular 13: lazy loading of named outlets

Tags: angular, routes, lazy-loading, angular13

**What I want**

I want to route to /edit/foo and lazy-load the correct modules.

**What I get**

When I try to call /edit/foo I get an Error:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'edit/foo'

**What I have:**

I have a component with two router-outlets:

```
<!-- vertical-splitscreen.component.html -->

<div class="container-fluid m-0 p-0">
  <div class="row m-0 p-0">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-7 m-0 p-0">
      <router-outlet name="left"></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-5 m-0 p-0">
      <router-outlet name="right"></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have also a root tree with lazy loading:

```
/* app-routing.module.ts */

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/edit',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'edit',
    loadChildren: () => import('./routes/edit-routing.module').then(m => m.EditRoutingModule),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  },
];
```

.

```
/* edit-routing.module.ts */

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: VerticalSplitscreenComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () => import('../modules/preview/preview.module').then(m => m.PreviewModule),
        outlet: 'left',
      },
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () => import('../modules/edit-form/edit-form.module').then(m => m.EditFormModule),
        outlet: 'right',
      },
    ],
  }
];
```

.

```
/* edit-form-routing.module.ts */

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'foo',
    component: EditFormComponent,
  },
];
```

**What confuses me**

When I remove the name "right" of the outlet, it works. Check the following changes:

In vertical-splitscreen.component.html

```
<router-outlet name="right"></router-outlet>
```

becomes

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

and in edit-routing.module.ts the line

```
outlet: 'right',
```

has to be deleted.

**Conclusion and question**

Actually it should work but it does not since there is a named outlet. So, is there any advice or workaround to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You are importing the `EditRoutingModule` instead of `EditModule`

Should be:

```
/* app-routing.module.ts */

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/edit',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'edit',
    loadChildren: () => import('./routes/edit.module').then(m => m.EditModule),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  },
];
```

and make sure to load the `EditRoutingModule` inside `EditModule`

Comment: What is the difference between importing the "EditRoutingModule" directly and having a parent "EditModule" that loads the "EditRoutingModule"?

Comment: Mmmm yea I suppose you are correct